# Confusing evaluation of $args in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, arguments

The $args variable should, by definition, contain all arguments passed to a script function. However if I construct a pipeline inside my function, the $args variable evaluates to null. Anyone knows why?

See this example:

```
function test { 1..3 | % { echo "args inside pipeline: $args" } ; echo "args outside pipeline: $args" }
```

This is the output, when passing parameter "hello":

```
PS> test hello
args inside pipeline:
args inside pipeline:
args inside pipeline:
args outside pipeline: hello
```

Is there a specific reason for this? I know how to work around this, however I wonder if anonye out there can explain the reason for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipes use $input. Try this:

```
function test { 1..3 | % { echo "args inside pipeline: $input" } ; echo "args outside pipeline: $args" }
```

Comment: Ok thanks. However I'd still say that this behavior is very strange. And according to the dev's they tried hard to design it using the Principle Of Least Surprise ;)

Comment: To explain what is going on here, $args contains every uncaptured (for lack of a better term) argument to a command.  In your pipeline example, you are asking for left over $args from the ForEach-Object (%) command, because that is the context that the script block will be evaluated in.

Comment: This kind of thing also happens with the $_ automatic variable.  You need to watch what context it is in.